# COALESCE doesn't return result

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Database: SQL Server 2008

I have this SQL query:

```
DECLARE @var FLOAT;
SET @var = (SELECT field FROM table);
-- SELECT @var returns [NULL]

SELECT COALESCE(@var, 'NI');
```

`[NULL]` is an intermediate result for `@var` variable. I expect COALESCE to return 'NI', however I get following error message:

> SQL Error[8114][S0005]: Error converting data type varchar to float.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: @marc_s according to the error message, this looks like [tag:sql-server]

Comment: @Mureinik: looks like it - agreed - but it would be better if the OP actually **told us**

Comment: sql server. Thanks!

Comment: @marc_s definitely, no argument here

Comment: You can't shove a string in to a float.  Why do you WANT to return a string if the float is NULL?  (Inconsitency in your datatypes is a very strong code smell.)

Comment: Again, the [official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/coalesce-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) should always be your first port of call when trying to work out why a function behaves as it does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With

```
SELECT COALESCE(@var, 'NI');
```

the DBMS sees that you want to replace the float number `@var` with another value in case it is null. In order to do so, it tries to make the second parameter a float, too. But `'NI'` cannot be converted to float of course.

Make the query return a string instead, i.e. convert your float to a string. E.g.:

```
SELECT COALESCE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), @var, 3), 'NI');
```

Comment: This means that whatever consumes the result is receiving a string representation of a float, that may sometimes actually be the characters 'NI'. While it "runs", I'd also suggest it's a very poor design choice, I'd even go as far as saying it's a code smell, and a pretty strong smell at that. The OP should probably be advised to reconsider Why they even want this to work, there are very likely much better approaches.

Answer (score 1):

As explained at [`Coalesce`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/coalesce-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#return-types): "Returns the data type of *expression* with the highest data type precedence. If all expressions are nonnullable, the result is typed as nonnullable."

More generally, the rules of [data type precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-precedence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) state that when you combine a `varchar` (`'NI'`) and a `float` (`@var`) in an expression (`COALESCE(@var, 'NI')`) then the `varchar` is [converted implicitly](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#implicit-conversions) to a `float`.

[`'NI'`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knights_Who_Say_%22Ni!%22) doesn't make a very good `float` (and isn't a [witch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dunking)).

Answer (score -1):

Is the value 'NI' just a string (char)? I expect so.
COALESCE is expecting compatible types as arguments. In your case it is a float and a char/varchar. So you have first to cast the float to a char and then apply the COALESCE function:

```
print COALESCE(CAST(@var AS CHAR), 'NI');
```

Comment: @MatBailie From [`char`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/char-and-varchar-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#remarks): "When _n_ isn't specified in a data definition or variable declaration statement, the default length is 1. If _n_ isn't specified when using the CAST and CONVERT functions, the default length is 30." The best practice is to _always_ specify the length.